# Wanting Sqlite SELECT statement to return default values if not existing for keys in a list

Tags: sqlite, select, where-clause, where-in

I have the following table with a sample entry in SQLITE:

`CREATE TABLE image (key CHAR(128) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value CHAR(32) NOT NULL);`
`INSERT INTO image VALUES ('key1', 'value1');`

I would like to be able to do a lookup for a list of keys `['key1','key2']` in single SQL statement. The expected response I would like is as follows:

```
| key        | value         |
|************|***************|
| key1       | value1        |
| key2       | default       |
```

I've looked around but am unable to figure this out. I've tried the following

```
SELECT key, IFNULL(value, 'default') value FROM image WHERE key IN ('key1', 'key2');
```

and other variants involving coalesce, etc but this only returns values for `key1` and not for `key2` (which I know is the expected behaviour).

How can I write a single SELECT statement that gives me the above expected response? I can't seem to figure this out for the life of me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query can return only rows that actually exist in some table/view/subquery in the FROM clause; nothing you do in the SELECT expression list can change that.

So you have to create some rows with these values (with a subquery or [common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html)), and then check whether there are matching rows in the table (with an [outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join)):

```
WITH list(key) AS (
  VALUES ('key1'), ('key2')
)
SELECT key,
       IFNULL(value, 'default') AS value
FROM list
LEFT JOIN image USING (key);
```

Comment: It works great. I've never actually heard of WITH LIST in sqlite. Learnt something new today!